# What does "hype high on java" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> For newbies, those who have simply e-mailed or surfed
>   the Web, the “community” of the Net is an odd sort of mysticism. How can
>   anyone think of these pages full of advertisements and spinning icons as a
>   community, or even as a space? To the sober newbie, **this just sounds like
>   hype high on java**. [[Source](https://books.google.iq/books?id=ju04DgAAQBAJ&pg=PT99&lpg=PT99&dq=These%20differences%20come%20inpart%20from%20differences%20in%20the%20people%20who%20populate%20these%20places,%20but%20demographics%20alone%20don%E2%80%99t%20explain%20the%20variance.%20Something%20more%20is%20going%20on.&source=bl&ots=phnfMoFow5&sig=ZuQ7LN_2emfsJlQxTK075pcLfjk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi0hfvo5vHcAhWCwVkKHS-pCpQQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ)]

What does the last sentence mean? Is this an idiom? Is *java* meant *coffee* here, or does it refer to the software?

Comment: *this just sounds like hype [**from someone who is**] high on java* (seriously caffeinated coffee).

Comment: It's a pun on both: the language as the medium of internet programming, and the drink as a stimulant. *Hype* you can look up; the author means that to those unfamiliar with the internet the notion that it is a "community" looks like unfounded enthusiasm.

Comment: StoneyB, that sounds more like an answer than a comment.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pun; they mean it in both contexts. Java is a sort of hidden language of the web, mentioned offhandedly by developers but rarely seen by the common person. Hence the 'mystical' aspects. The 'spinning icons' comment references the jitters of an over-caffeinated individual. It makes the point that the both frenetic and opaque nature of the web doesn't lend itself to what a first-time user would normally consider a community.